# Adding file to crontab via php script

Tags: php, shell

I've found at [this forum](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/17896-can-we-edit-crontab-using-shell-script.html) that it is possible to edit crontab like this:
a. crontab -l > $tmpfile
b. edit $tmpfile
c. crontab $tmpfile
d. rm $tmpfile
So, I'm trying to implement this solution on php:

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('myhost');
if (!$ssh->login('user', 'password')) 
{
    echo'Login Failed';
}

    $ssh->exec('crontab -l > /var/www/tmp.txt');
    $content=file_get_contents("/var/www/tmp.txt");
    $content.='0 0 1 * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/clearPreviousMonth1.php';
    $file=fopen("/var/www/tmp.txt", "w");
    fputs($file,$content);
    fclose($file);
    $ssh->exec('crontab /var/www/tmp.txt');
    echo $content;
```

I can see edited content of crontab in my browser and tmp file, but when I use **crontab -e** it's not changed. What's my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add new string before the end of file. In other case it's not added to crontab.
changed `$content.='0 0 1 * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/clearPreviousMonth1.php';`
to `$content.="0 0 1 * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/clearPreviousMonth1.php\n";`
note that it's neccessary to use `"` instead of `'`, because it just will append `\n` symbols to last string